# Python type-hinting a mixin with its own properties

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I know that I need to use a **Protocol** if I want to type-hint a Mixin class.

```
from typing import Protocol


class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    a: int


class MyMixin:
    def method(self: MyProtocol):
        return self.a * 10
```

Here we type-hinting **self** and this does the job.
The problem arises when MyMixin also has its own properties/methods not related to Protocol class

```
class MyMixin:
    b: int

    def method(self: MyProtocol):
        return self.a * self.b  # here should be typing error, MyProtocol has no "b"
```

How to properly resolve this kind of case?

Answer (score 0):

- `MyMixin` is not (inherited from) `MyProtocol`. Should probably be:

```
class MyMixin(MyProtocol):
    ...
```

- If your method expects something that has `.b` it should annotate `self` with something that has `.b` (i.e. `MyMixin` not `MyProtocol`).
- Annotating `self` is redundant. It should always be the class the method belongs to.

Comment: Check this about using Protocol
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#mixin-classes

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Never heard of that approach. But I don't understand why to avoid inheritance from `MyProtocol`, it seems less explicit to me

Comment: @AntonM. whilst it's apparently valid for mypy, that style doesn't appear in the [Protocol PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)

Answer (score 0):

This *is* actually covered by [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols) (see "intersections").

@Yevhen-Kuzmovych is right, your mixin can simply inherit from your protocol. Mixins are by definition not supposed to be instantiated themselves, so doing that is not an issue:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    a: int

class MyMixin(MyProtocol):
    b: int

    def method(self) -> int:
        return self.a * self.b

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int) -> None:
        self.a = a

class Foo(MyMixin, A):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b = b

foo = Foo(21, 2)
print(foo.method())
```

An alternative approach would be to just extend your protocol. The same logic applies: IMHO a mixin should not even have internal state. It should rely on a host class that inherits from a base class, which in turn provides the state that the mixin relies on to function. Mixins should really only ever provide additional methods. Thus, another solution is simply this:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    a: int
    b: int

class MyMixin:
    def method(self: MyProtocol) -> int:
        return self.a * self.b

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int) -> None:
        self.a = a

class Foo(MyMixin, A):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b = b

foo = Foo(21, 2)
print(foo.method())
```

This expresses that `MyMixin` relies on the host class to provide the attributes `a` and `b` because it does. But I suppose that point is up for debate.

Both obviously output `42` and both pass `mypy --strict`.

Comment: I guess this does not also make `a` and `b` in any way a class variable, as they are immutable scalars. I have found the language documentation quite [scant](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/) about the nuances of such variable definitions outside of a class method. The [protocols PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation) does seem to imply variables defined this way in a protocol may not become class variables, but ... leaves this point quite ambiguous IMHO, in its single example of this case.

Comment: @matanster I don't understand what you mean. The question never mentioned class variables. Furthermore, whether or not something is a class variable or an instance variable is orthogonal to its mutability. Lastly, PEP 526 [explicitly states](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) that class variables should be declared using [`ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) and PEP 544 picks this up in the last paragraph of [the section on protocol members](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#protocol-members).

Comment: I guess your reading of the PEP was better than mine